# Merging a date and time into one moment object to compare against today

Tags: reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I'm currently implementing moment in my React project to format dates of schedules set up in the database for sending notifications. My system has a dashboard displaying all notifications scheduled to go out and their respective dates. The database currently has two columns for recording the scheduled date and time - `schedule_date` and `schedule_time` - and currently I display them on the dashboard using the following code:

```
{moment(file.schedule.schedule_date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}
{moment(file.schedule.schedule_time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('h:mma')}
```

`schedule_date` has the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and `schedule_time` has the format `HH:MM:SS` (pseudo) However, I need now to be able to compare this date with the current date in order to determine whether or not the set schedule for a notification has passed. I used the following code to get today's date and time:

```
let now = moment();
```

But I am having difficulty being able to compare this against the actual date / time in the database. I don't want to just compare against the date because if the notification was due to go out at 9.00am and it's now 10.00am it would still assume it hadn't been sent if it was only compared against date.

Is there a way to do this comparison in the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the time to your date's moment object this way :

```js
var date = '2018-09-12T00:00:00Z';
var time = '16:00:00';

var momentDate = moment(date);
var momentTime = moment(time, 'HH:mm:ss');

momentDate = momentDate.set({
  hour: momentTime.get('hour'),
  minute: momentTime.get('minute'),
  second: momentTime.get('second')
});

console.log(momentDate.format());
console.log(momentDate.isAfter(moment.now()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

You can also try to create the iso date format from your date and time strings directly like this :

```
var fullDate = date + 'T' + time + 'Z';
```